# Xilinx VCU encoder motion vector buffer

Tags: c++, video, embedded-linux, h.264, xilinx

I'm using the Xilinx Ultrascale+ series ZU5 processor, and it comes packaged with IP that includes it's PL VCU h26x encoder/decoder. The datasheet for the VCU mentions a motion vector buffer that is allocated for the encoded stream, which I must assume is where the motion vectors are stored between encoded frames. Unfortunately Xilinx doesn't explain much about the buffer, and most importantly leaves out the memory map that describes how vectors are stored in the buffer.

The IP itself isn't technically owned by Xilinx, it's licensed from a third party known as Allegro dvt. I've thrown the question at Xilinx and Allegro, but neither have responded... I've also dumped the raw buffer to try and cross reference the data with the motion vectors that are extracted by FFMpeg, but it hasn't lead to much insight.

How are motion vectors arranged in the buffer?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "My question is whether anyone has worked with this IP that knows the motion vector buffer structure. " suppose you find someone who can answer this positive. What question would you ask them? post that question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number delete and make a repost? Modify the title? Edit the body of the question? Which one?

Comment: I would suggest the latter. Clarify the quesiton to ask for somethign specific by editing it

Comment: you were still asking if there is someone who already worked with it and can answer... thats redundant. You posted a question and users who know the answer will post an answer. Not sure if the question is now specific enough, though I am not the one who can answer ;)